# Erro na instalação de bibliotecas python pelo cmd

Tags: python

Estou querendo instalar a biblioteca pywhatkit do python pelo cmd, porém, quando eu coloco o comando " pip install pywhatkit" ele baixa e instala até certo ponto. Segue as informações que aparece no cmd:

PS C:\Users\João Pedro> pip install pywhatkit
Collecting pywhatkit

Using cached pywhatkit-3.8-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4

Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>1.2

Using cached soupsieve-2.1-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Collecting Pillow

Using cached Pillow-8.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting pyautogui

Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.52.tar.gz (55 kB)
Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5

Using cached PyGetWindow-0.0.9.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21

Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.26.tar.gz (23 kB)
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1

Using cached PyTweening-1.0.3.zip (15 kB)
Collecting mouseinfo

Using cached MouseInfo-0.1.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting pymsgbox

Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)

Installing build dependencies ... done

Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

```
**Preparing wheel metadata ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\joão pedro\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\joão pedro\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7cn2sra0'
     cwd: C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yerfq6kz\pymsgbox_9ed5c5dfd5e041d48e433cfd48e25387
Complete output (14 lines):
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: unexpected end of data (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info
writing C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-lvgd0vdz\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'**
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\joão pedro\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\joão pedro\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\João Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7cn2sra0' Check the logs for full command output.

Gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para resolver esse problema, sou iniciante na programação e estou aprendendo a programa em python. Desde já, grato a sua atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro na verdade pode ajudar mais gente - o problema não é a instalação do `pywhatkit` - mas sim, que o Python não encontrou o `bdist_wheel` no caminho.

Quando isso acontece, pode ser necessário instalar o os pacotes `wheel` e `bdist_wheel` manualmente -

```
pip install wheel
pip install bdist_wheel
```

Veja a resposta no stackoverflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci

Answer (score 0):

Na pagina **pywhatkit**  no lado a um link  com o nome "Baixar arquivos" , clique e sera baixado o arquivo zipado.

Extraia o arquivo e entre na pasta e insira a seguinte instrução:

```
python setup.py install
```

Se o erro persistir informe a versão do python a também se não estou errado para o sistema Windows `pipwin install <package>`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver. Obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta funcionou, não esqueça de marcar ela como "aceita". Essa forma ajuda quando apenas um pacote falha na instalação, mas é melhor arrumar a instalação por pip, por que aí os updates e instalações de outros pacotes vão funcionar também.